# Under-replicated blocks count is inaccurate, but why?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am getting wildly varying reports of under-replicated blocked. I am wondering what's causing this. `hadoop dfsadmin -metasave` reports ~232,000 MISSING blocks awaiting replication. How do I fix this? Jobs run just fine and there does not appear to be data missing.

Please see output from `hadoop fsck /`, `hadoop dfsadmin -report`, `hadoop dfsadmin -metasave`, and the namenode web GUI below:

`hadoop fsck /`:

```
 Total size:    6066860793495 B (Total open files size: 47000701003 B)
 Total dirs:    1801
 Total files:   230828 (Files currently being written: 493)
 Total blocks (validated):      242592 (avg. block size 25008494 B) (Total open file blocks (not validated): 681)
 Minimally replicated blocks:   242592 (100.0 %)
 Over-replicated blocks:        0 (0.0 %)
 Under-replicated blocks:       932 (0.38418415 %)
 Mis-replicated blocks:         0 (0.0 %)
 Default replication factor:    3
 Average block replication:     2.9945753
 Corrupt blocks:                0
 Missing replicas:              1851 (0.25479725 %)
 Number of data-nodes:          20
 Number of racks:               1
FSCK ended at Thu Nov 03 10:17:47 CDT 2011 in 7359 milliseconds
```

`hadoop dfsadmin -report`:

```
Configured Capacity: 59070545264640 (53.72 TB)
Present Capacity: 56867905841329 (51.72 TB)
DFS Remaining: 37637696475136 (34.23 TB)
DFS Used: 19230209366193 (17.49 TB)
DFS Used%: 33.82%
Under replicated blocks: 245346
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 73
Missing blocks: 0
```

metasave output...
hadoop dfsadmin -metasave output excerpt:

```
232461 files and directories, 243290 blocks = 475751 total
Live Datanodes: 20
Dead Datanodes: 0
Metasave: Blocks waiting for replication: 242747
```

There are about 1000 actual files being replicated(or waiting) and then ~232,000 files "MISSING" all similar to:

```
: blk_2551072940280567829_12480437 MISSING (replicas: l: 0 d: 0 c: 0 e: 0)
: blk_2565249812869117144_12480431 MISSING (replicas: l: 0 d: 0 c: 0 e: 0)
: blk_2950011510944289339_12480413 MISSING (replicas: l: 0 d: 0 c: 0 e: 0)
: blk_3809337797233614456_12456357 MISSING (replicas: l: 0 d: 0 c: 0 e: 0)
: blk_3809337797233614456_12463021 MISSING (replicas: l: 0 d: 0 c: 0 e: 0)
: blk_3809337797233614456_12468869 MISSING (replicas: l: 0 d: 0 c: 0 e: 0)
: blk_3809337797233614456_12474511 MISSING (replicas: l: 0 d: 0 c: 0 e: 0)
: blk_3811560762593023914_12440928 MISSING (replicas: l: 0 d: 0 c: 0 e: 0)
: blk_3811560762593023914_12449396 MISSING (replicas: l: 0 d: 0 c: 0 e: 0)
: blk_3811560762593023914_12462184 MISSING (replicas: l: 0 d: 0 c: 0 e: 0)
: blk_3811560762593023914_12465792 MISSING (replicas: l: 0 d: 0 c: 0 e: 0)
: blk_3811560762593023914_12472905 MISSING (replicas: l: 0 d: 0 c: 0 e: 0)
: blk_3812070171484751861_12436051 MISSING (replicas: l: 0 d: 0 c: 0 e: 0)
: blk_3815454413870879906_12441243 MISSING (replicas: l: 0 d: 0 c: 0 e: 0)
Metasave: Blocks being replicated: 0
Metasave: Blocks 29 waiting deletion from 17 datanodes.
```

Namenode web GUI:

```
Cluster Summary
232390 files and directories, 243235 blocks = 475625 total. Heap Size is 1.84 GB / 8.68 GB (21%)
Configured Capacity :   53.72 TB
DFS Used    :   17.46 TB
Non DFS Used    :   2 TB
DFS Remaining   :   34.26 TB
DFS Used%   :   32.51 %
DFS Remaining%  :   63.77 %
Live Nodes  :   20
Dead Nodes  :   0
Decommissioning Nodes   :   0
Number of Under-Replicated Blocks   :   242532
```

!! Update: !!

I believe that this must be a bug as the number of "under-replicated" blocks is now nearing one million. We do not have near that number of actual blocks on the cluster so this must be a bug.

The web GUI now shows the following:

```
Cluster Summary
234877 files and directories, 250074 blocks = 484951 total. Heap Size is 706.5 MB/8.68 GB (7%)
Configured Capacity :   53.72 TB
DFS Used    :   20.71 TB
Non DFS Used    :   1.54 TB
DFS Remaining   :   31.47 TB
DFS Used%   :   38.56 %
DFS Remaining%  :   58.58 %
Live Nodes  :   20
Dead Nodes  :   0
Decommissioning Nodes   :   0
Number of Under-Replicated Blocks   :   451014
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I obtained a response from Todd Lipcon of Cloudera. I wanted to update this question in case others have this issue. I noticed this issue with CDH3u1 and this was the response:

"
The "append" function is known to be broken in CDH3 and is likely to
have bugs like this. We would recommend you advise your users to not
use it. This is true of all releases of Hadoop 0.20.x (CDH and
otherwise) and will be fixed in CDH4 (upstream version 0.23 or above).

Sorry for the bad news. I'll look into this particular bug to make
sure it isn't present in the upstream trunk, but it's unlikely to be
fixed in a CDH3 release.
"